# Foursquare Tips: difference between API and Explore on the website

Tags: ios, api, foursquare

I am searching for tips with a keyword but I've noticed that the results I get via API are different from the ones I get from the Foursquare website, in particular via the Explore section (https://it.foursquare.com/explore).

This is the API call: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/search?ll=41.887944,12.500657&query=keyword&limit=500&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&v=20120101

Answer (score 0):

The Explore feature uses the [/venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint, not /tips/search.

Comment: Ok but then why I can't find a tip via /tips/search and I can see it via /venues/explore?

Comment: I would need an example to help you debug particular issues

Comment: Example: why can't i find this tip (text="Ambiente grande ed originale. Buono per aperitivo, soprattutto se si resta per il dopocena.") that contains the word "aperitivo" (https://it.foursquare.com/v/caff%C3%A8-letterario/4adcdac4f964a520885221e3) when I do a tips/search with query=aperitivo?

Comment: what was the API call you made where it didn't come back? (with client_id/client_secret omitted)

Comment: this is it: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/search?ll=41.86085,12.47810&query=aperitivo&limit=500&client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy&v=20120101

Comment: the api is returning the max number of results, so presumably this tip just doesn't rank highly enough.

Comment: I see. But then how is the ranking calculated? What makes a tip rank higher than another?

Comment: A variety of factors, but the two main ones are distance and popularity.